# Closure of a set in weird Topological Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am currently taking a Topology course and I try to find some problems online and try to solve them. The obvious downside is that, more often then not, I can not seem to find solutions to check my work or get a hint! So, hopefully someone here can give a hint or solution.

Here is the question:

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a set and $A \mapsto \overline{A}$ be an operation on the subsets of $\mathbb{X}$ satisfying:

1.) $A \subseteq \overline{A}$

2.) $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{A}$

3.) $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$

4.) $\overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset$

Let $\tau$ be defined by $A \in \tau \iff \overline{\mathbb{X} - A} = \mathbb{X} - A$. You may assume $\tau$ is a topology on $\mathbb{X}$. Show that $cl_{\tau}(A) = \overline{A}$ for all $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$.

Here is my attempt that seems to be continuously leading me to dead ends:

By definition $cl_{\tau}(A) = \bigcap \{F: A \subseteq F \text{ and } F \text{ closed}\}$, so for any $F \in cl_{\tau}(A)$ the following inclusions and implications hold: $(A \subseteq F) \implies (F^c \subseteq A^c) \implies (\mathbb{X} - A^c \subseteq \mathbb{X} - F^c)$. However, $F \text{ closed} \implies F^c \text{ open(i.e. in the topology)}$. Hence, by the topology defined we have the following equality is true: $\overline{\mathbb{X} - F^c} = \mathbb{X} - F^c$. Now, by the last implication we have the following holds: $\mathbb{X} - A^c \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{X} - F^c}$. This is where I get stuck...

Thanks to whoever can help or give insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{F}=\{F\subseteq\Bbb X:A\subseteq F\text{ and }F\text{ is closed}\}$. If $F\in\mathscr{F}$, then $\overline A\subseteq\overline F=F$. To see this, note that $A\cup F=F$, so

$$\overline F=\overline{A\cup F}=\overline A\cup\overline F\,,$$

and therefore $\overline A\subseteq\overline F$. Thus, $\overline A\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{F}$. On the other hand, $\overline{\overline A}=\overline A$, so $\overline A$ is closed, and certainly $A\subseteq\overline A$, so $\overline A\in\mathscr{F}$, and therefore $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\subseteq\overline A$. This shows that $\overline A=\bigcap\mathscr{F}=\operatorname{cl}_\tau(A)$.

Note that the statement $F\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau(A)$ in your argument makes no sense, since both $F$ and $\operatorname{cl}_\tau(A)$ are subsets of $\Bbb X$; $F\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_\tau(A)$ would at least be a possible statement, but it appears from what follows that you actually meant that $F\in\mathscr{F}$ as I defined $\mathscr{F}$.

This isn’t actually weird: **any** topological space can be defined in this way. There are several provably equivalent ways to define topological spaces: in terms of topologies (i.e., families of open sets satisfying certain axioms), in terms of families of closed sets, in terms of neighborhood bases, and more. Here you’re showing that topological spaces can be defined in terms of a *closure operator* that satisfies certain axioms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one question, however. How can you say $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{F}$? I know it is true, but based on properties (1)-(4) how can you conclude that? Thank you.

Comment: @DaltonPettway: I should have included that; for some reason I was thinking when I wrote the answer that it was one of the axioms, as they’re sometimes given that way. It follows from the third one, and I’ve now added that argument.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the note as well, very insightful.

Comment: @DaltonPettway: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hey Brain, I noticed that you also wrote $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{A}$, so $\overline{A}$ is closed. I know you are using property 2.), however, are you also using the theorem that says $A \text{ closed} \iff A = \overline{A}$? If so, do you think it would be valid to use here? I know it can be easily shown that $(\overline{A})^c$ is open (i.e in the topology) using axiom 2.), hence, $\overline{A}$ is closed.

Comment: @DaltonPettway: I’m actually using the definition of $\tau$: $\overline{\overline A}=\overline A$ means that by definition $\Bbb X\setminus\overline A\in\tau$, which in turn means that $\overline A$ is $\tau$-closed. I can’t use the theorem that $A$ is closed iff $A=\overline A$, because that’s basically what’s being proved in this problem.

Comment: Ah I see! Also, I had not realized that this problem is basically asking to prove $A$ is closed iff $A = \overline{A}$, that is quite interesting...! Thank you again!

Comment: @DaltonPettway: You’re very welcome!